# Exercises 6 and 7 in 1.1 (page 4) of Topology and Groupoids, by Ronald Brown

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, real-numbers

I am not sure which keywords to use to search for previously asked questions dealing with these problems. I did search for "Topology and Groupoids" but didn't find anything relevant.

**Problems:**

> 6. Let $C$ be a neighborhood of $c \in \mathbb{R}$, and let $a + b = c$. Prove that there are neighborhoods $A$ of $a$ and $B$ of $b$ such that $x \in A$ and $y \in B$ imply $x + y \in C$.

> 7. Write down and prove a similar result to that of Exercise 6, but with $c = ab$.

**Other information:**

The definition of a neighborhood used in the book is (from page 1) that $N$ is a neighborhood of $a$ if there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $(a - \delta, a + \delta) \subseteq N$.

**Attempt for Exercise 6:**

By assumption there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $(c - \delta, c + \delta) \subseteq C$. We know that $a + b = c$, so we see that

\begin{align*}
\Big( a - \frac{\delta}{2} \Big) + \Big( b - \frac{\delta}{2} \Big) &= c - \delta\\
\Big( a + \frac{\delta}{2} \Big) + \Big( b + \frac{\delta}{2} \Big) &= c + \delta.
\end{align*}

Therefore if $x \in \big( a - \frac{\delta}{2}, a + \frac{\delta}{2} \big)$ and $y \in \big( b - \frac{\delta}{2}, b + \frac{\delta}{2} \big)$, we see that $x + y \in (a + b - \delta, a + b + \delta) = (c - \delta, c + \delta) \subseteq C$. Let $A = \big( a - \frac{\delta}{2}, a + \frac{\delta}{2} \big)$ and $B = \big( b - \frac{\delta}{2}, b + \frac{\delta}{2} \big)$ and the proof is complete.

**Attempt for Exercise 7:**

We know there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $(c - \delta, c + \delta) \subseteq C$. Since $ab = c$, we see that

\begin{align*}
(a - \sqrt{\delta})(b + \sqrt{\delta}) &= ab - \delta,
\end{align*}

so for $0 < \sqrt{\epsilon} < \sqrt{\delta}$, we have

\begin{align*}
ab - \delta < (a - \sqrt{\epsilon})(b + \sqrt{\epsilon}) < ab.
\end{align*}

This suggests that $x \in (a - \sqrt{\delta}, a)$ and $y \in (b, b + \sqrt{\delta})$ will work.

The problem is that I'm suspicious my proposed solution will not work if I let $x$ and $y$ vary independently. For example, it's not clear to me if

\begin{align*}
ab - \delta < \big( a - \frac{\sqrt{\delta}}{2} \big) \big( b + \frac{\sqrt{\delta}}{4} \big) < ab + \delta
\end{align*}

is true or not.

**Question:**

Can anyone check my proof for Exercise 6, and tell me what's wrong with my attempted proof of Exercise 7? Thank you.

Comment: I think you've made an error asserting $(a-\sqrt{\delta})(b+\sqrt{\delta}) = ab - \delta$. Your proof for 6 looks correct.

Comment: @masiewpao I think you're right. An embarrassing algebra error. I'll have to come back and try another approach.

Comment: Happens to me all the time!!

Comment: If you do an MSE search for "multiplication is continuous", you should find some help.

Comment: @RobArthan If I understand correctly, you're saying that Exercise 7 can be understood as asking for a proof that the limit of the product of two sequences is the product of the limits? I searched for "multiplication is continuous" and that's all I was able to glean.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ n$ enough great such that

$$0<a-\frac 1n<x<a+\frac 1n$$
$$0<b-\frac 1n<y<b+\frac 1n$$

then

$$0<ab -\frac 1n(a+b)+\frac{1}{n^2}<xy<ab+\frac 1n(a+b)+\frac{1}{n^2}$$

and
$$|ab-xy|<\frac{|a+b|}{n} +\frac{1}{n^2}$$

Since $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{|a+b|}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}=0$$
we can choose $ n$ such that
$$\frac{|a+b|}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}<\delta$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What if $a$ or $b$ negative (or both)?